# select parent node containing text inside children's node

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

basically i want to select a node (div) in which it's children node's(h1,b,h3) contain specified text.

```
<html>
<div id="contents">
<p>
<h1> Child text 1</h1>
<b> Child text 2 </b>
...
</p>
<h3> Child text 3 </h3>
</div>
```

i am expecting, /html/div/ not /html/div/h1

i have this below, but unfortunately returns the children, instead of the xpath to the div.

```
expression = "//div[contains(text(), 'Child text 1')]"
doc.xpath(expression)
```

i am expecting, /html/div/ not /html/div/h1

So is there a way to do this simply with xpath syntax?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could append "/.." to anchor back to the parent. Not sure if there's a more robust method.

```
expression = "//div[contains(text(), 'Child text 1')]/.."
```

Comment: what does that mean by append "/.."

Comment: it means to add, try the example I just added.

Comment: wow that works ! not sure what it means by anchor back to parent ? does it find the immediate ancestor? what if i need to go back to the root that contains the div ? so the parent's parent. would i just do 

      expression = "//html[contains(text(), "Child text 1")]/.."

Answer (score 17):

The following expression gives a node (div) in which any children nodes (not just h1,b,h3) contain specified text (not the div itself):

```
doc.xpath('//div[.//*[contains(text(), "Child text 1")]]')
```

you can refine that and return the only the div with the id `contents` like in your example:

```
doc.xpath('//div[@id="contents" and .//*[contains(text(), "Child text 1")]]')
```

It does not match, if the text is a text node of the div (directly inside the div), which is my interpretation of the question.